# Check that a class is present on multiple elements on Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I use this function to check if an element has or not an specific class:

```
hasClass: function (element, cls) {
    return element.getAttribute('class').then(function (classes) {
        return classes.split(' ').indexOf(cls) !== -1;
    });
}
```

I have several elements in a page that can include an specific class ("is-break") to change it's style. All those elements have this "free-terms-center__day-list--el__wrapper" class.

I'm doing something like:

```
 element.all(by.css(".free-terms-center__day-list--el__wrapper")).count().then(value=>{

        for (let index = 0; index < value; index++) {
            console.log("heheh")
            expect( helper.hasClass(element.all(by.css(".free-terms-center__day-list--el__wrapper")).get(index), ".is-break")).to.eventually.equal(true);

        }

    })
```

And doesn't seems to work, the hasClass is returning me false inside the for loop, but the class is present on the elements.

But if i do something like this:

```
    const blocks =  element.all(by.css(".free-terms-center__day-list--el__wrapper"));

    expect( helper.hasClass(blocks.first(), ".is-break")).to.eventually.equal(true);
    expect( helper.hasClass(blocks.last(), ".is-break")).to.eventually.equal(true);
    expect( helper.hasClass(blocks.get(5), ".is-break")).to.eventually.equal(true);
```

Works

I guess it's something promise-related, but can I do all the expects inside the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `chai-as-promised` library, you can siplify your whole code to:

```
element.all(by.css('.free-terms-center__day-list--el__wrapper')).each((elementToCheck) => {
    expect(elementToCheck.getAttribute('class')).to.eventually.contains('is-break');
});
```